# Update list of Maven archetypes in IntelliJ "New Project" > "Maven" tab

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, updates, maven-archetype

How do I update the list of Maven archetypes listed in "New Project" dialog box in IntelliJ IDEA version 2017.2?

[image]

Comment: Try reindexing the repositories, also vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65803.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Manually trigger update of Maven cache

IntelliJ 2017.2 is not so "intelli" with Maven. You must manually invoke an update of the Maven cache of repository information listing archetypes.

1. Go to: `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Maven` > `Repositories`.
2. For each of the items you care about in the list of `Indexed Maven Repositories`, click the row, wait a moment, then click the `Update` button.
3. Wait a long while, several minutes or more as the local repository cache is synched with the repository servers on the internet.

[image: screen shot of list of Maven repositories in IntelliJ 2017.2]

There is an [open feature request to add automatic update](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65803) of the Maven cache when opening the `New Project` wizard.