# IntelliJ 2017.2 stuck on `Loading archetype list` for `New Project` > `Maven`

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

When choosing the `Create New Project` option after launching IntelliJ 2017.2, I get this endlessly spinning wheel on the `Maven` tag, saying “Loading archetype list…”.

[image: screen shot of New Project wizard panel]

Any way to get to a Maven archetype?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. If there is OOM in the log, increase the heap size for maven importer process in IntelliJ IDEA settings.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it in my case. It's just a bit confusing. The JVM options in `idea-UI-XXX/bin/idea64.vmoptions` are NOT the ones that set the maximum heap size for the Maven importer, you need to set them in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing`. See [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/maven-importing.html). The IDEA log can be found in `~/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/log/idea.log` (see [Locating IDE log files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: ...and also [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519). If you get the OOM in the IDEA log, there won't be any outward sign of anything wrong, the interface will just sit there, spinning its "please wait" wheel. In a successful archetype load, the process will use about 1.6GiB of RAM, and display the archetype list. Happens quickly, too.

Comment: Related: [*Update list of Maven archetypes in IntelliJ “New Project” > “Maven” tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45067555/642706)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Wait

Loading the full list of [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) seems to be quite an exertion for IntelliJ. Surprising, as I don't recall any such long delays in NetBeans.

So wait, be patient. **May take a couple minutes.** Make tea, pat the dog. Wait for the fan on your computer to spin up and then quiet again.

## Use more memory

I currently have `VM options for importer` set to `-Xmx2048m` as shown in the [Answer by Tonhofer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022546/642706).

I do not know if this point was key, but my problem has gone away «knock-on-wood». So this might be helping.

FYI… I have a 16-gig MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) running Sierra 10.12.6 with two Java implementations, Java 8 Update 144 from Oracle and Java 9 beta jdk-9+181 from OpenJDK.

## Quit, update repositories

While I do not understand what all is going on, it seems like this has been a workaround for me.

Quit IntelliJ, then launch again.

In Preferences/Settings, go to `Build, Execution, Deployment`> `Build Tools` > `Maven` > `Repositories`. Click each of the listed repositories, and click the `Update` button. A spinning wheel appears for the duration of the update.

A copy of each [repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)’s data is being downloaded and parsed on your local machine, descriptions of all the libraries known by that repository. Some of the repositories may be quite large with many listed projects. So this process may take a while, possibly more than several minutes.

When the updates are complete, try the `New Project` feature again.

Comment: It's been running for 1.5 hours now. No improvement. Although it quickly calmed down CPU-wise, luckily.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Should only be several minutes if you have a fast internet connection. I added another section: **quit, then update repositories**. I do *not* know for certain that this helps. But something I've done in my bumbling-about seems to have fixed the problem. Updating repositories may have helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the `-Xmx2048m` has no effect and you actually need  to increase the maximum heap size in the interface in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing`. See [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/maven-importing.html). That was confusing. Interesting, when profiling, the archetype load succeeds. Doubly confusing.

Answer (score 20):

I just hit this on 2017.2.3 (just updated now) on Fedora 24 (oops time to upgrade)

The immediate solution was to change the [Maven settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/maven-importing.html) (File > Settings > Maven) to use my on-machine Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144 instead the default "internal JRE" 1.8.0_152. Btw, the importer uses JVM option `-Xmx768m` by default.

[image]

And we go on...

Comment: Nope, wrong answer! It was the maximum heap size, see other comments.

Comment: plus 1, this helped me!

Answer (score 8):

Add more memory

`Settings` > `Maven` > `Importing`

`VM options for importer` **-Xm1024m** (or more)

Comment: I also ran into this problem, increasing the memory cleared it up right away.

Answer (score 1):

Closing out of IntelliJ and creating the project from this window helped:

[IntelliJ Welcome Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4OJG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by updating the NVIDIA driver, based on IntelliJ logs. Anything else did not work for me. The list loads now in a few seconds..finally.

Edit:
as Basil suggested, here are some clarifications. I am on Windows 10 Home Edition 64b, and I have IntelliJ 2017.2 with Java 1.8.0_152. I checked IntelliJ logs and followed a standard procedure: I went on Google and I searched by that exception (I can't remember what and where) and found a site where someone suggested to update my nVidia drivers. For the update, you only need to go to nVidia site and from that on it should be easy. I was on a 2016 driver and got to 2018 version after the update. I also have the previously added configurations from other comments.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Link to bug report. Explain how you updated the NVIDIA driver. What computer and OS was this? It is hard to imagine how a video driver would be impacting the display of Maven repository contents.

Comment: Anything else did not work for me, but your answer work well for me!