# IntelliJ idea can't update any maven repositories

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Problem:

I have a maven project that builds & compiles fine using maven tool from command-line.

Then I have IntelliJ IDEA that refuses to build said project, claiming that some of dependencies are not available.

I've found out that the root of the problem is in fact that IntelliJ can't connect to maven repositories which contain said dependencies. Of repositories, there are 3:

1. apache's maven repo (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
2. sonatype's oss repo (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
3. company's internal repo (url omitted)

All three are available, accessible through browser for viewing, and dependencies from them are fetched using maven command line interface.

But, IntelliJ just says ".. can't reconnect" and shows errors about updating said repos. I've tried to use different maven options (my local installation, 3.5.2; intellij's bundled maven2 and maven3), to no avail yet.

Any idea why that could happened?

Comment: have you checked your settings.xml file?

Comment: I didn't change anything there, and just removed ~/.m2 repo to be re-downloaded by mvn while building by-hand, so it should be all default. Looking into it now. Upd: yes, settings.xml just doesnt exist in ~/.m2 so all should be maven's defaults. Its not set to be overriden in IDEA as well.

Comment: The apache repo and sonatype snapshots are not used by default only Maven Central...nothing else if you don't have a settings.xml file...

Comment: repositories are declared in my `pom.xml` instead, not in settings.xml

Comment: @MikhailKrutov Does your project build from the command line Maven? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy...?

Comment: Have you tried quitting IntelliJ and rebooting the computer? Have you tried [clearing caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html) and restarting? What version of IntelliJ are you using? Have you tried updating to a later version of IntelliJ? For some other oddball things to try, see [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45365878/642706).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have run into this many times also and the only solution that has worked is to restart IntelliJ which has worked every time.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you work in a big company/corporation, there's a good chance you're using a proxy, be sure to ask your coworkers about configuring your connection. Also, there is probably some Artifactory/Nexus repository in use, which also needs to be configured to allow dependencies to be downloaded. All of this information should be included in the `settings.xml` file, which should be in the Maven settings (or other build tool, but I only used Maven).

The other thing is that there are problems with the Maven bundled into Intellij. I tried configuring it in many ways inside the IDE, but unfortunately nothing helped, even though the `settings.xml` file was in the `.m2` folder.

I installed a standalone Maven where I put the `settings.xml` file in the `/conf` folder. Then just point to the Maven location inside the IDE, preferably delete the contents of the `.m2` folder (this will remove both the local settings and the downloaded dependencies) and everything should work fine.

Also remember about VPN connection - sometimes downloading artifacts from repositories is only possible through it.